# How to direct internet connection to iPhone USB and not Wifi

Tags: network, wifi, internet

I have a Macbook Pro running macOS Sierra 10.12.6

I'm using Wifi to connect to a server using SSH. My iPhone is also connected to my laptop and both Wifi and iPhone USB have the green circle next to them in Network settings. How can I configure my network so that it uses my iPhone USB for Internet and Wifi for SSH?

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 34:36:3b:ce:3e:88 
    inet 192.168.1.247 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 22:3c:ae:94:e7:84 
    inet6 fe80::18a5:b2ff:226e:8492%en4 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xf.    
    inet 172.20.10.7 netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 172.20.10.15
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: 100baseTX <full-duplex>
    status: active
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways! First make sure that the iPhone is above WiFi in the network service order; that makes it the default for all traffic.  Then you can either:

1. Use SSH's `-b <ip>` flag to bind SSH to your desired IP. So if your *WiFi IP* is 
   `111.111.111.111`, ssh as per usual with `ssh -b 111.111.111.111`.
2. Add a static route to your remote host routing through the desired IP. If your desired IP to connect *from* is `111.111.111.111` and your remote host is `222.222.222.222`: `$ sudo route add 222.222.222.222 111.111.111.111`. then SSH normally. When you're done, tear down the route with `$ sudo route delete 222.222.222.222 111.111.111.111`.

Comment: Of course your IPs will likely change; try this out and once it's working you can script it so that you don't have to manually input your IPs every time. I would personally write a bash script and utilize probably sed, awk, grep, ifconfig, and cut. If you're better than me on the command line, you could probably do it just with ifconfig and awk.

Comment: The iPhone USB is not above Wifi in settings. How can I do that?

Comment: Click the gear icon, "set service order" and drag it above WiFi.